# appium returns 200 status code but the click is not performed on the device

Tags: android, selenium, web-applications, appium

I am stuck with a game application where the appium returns 200 status code for a spin click(none of the clicks on game page is working though appium returns 200 code) but the click is not performed on the device. It is a web application and I am using the real device. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using implicit, explicit waits, wait using Thread, Javascript, coordinates based click but no luck.

I am using the below code:

```
public class AndriodDriver {

AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

 @Test
public void testFirstCalculator() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy S7");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");


    driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new 
    URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://pa03-mob.wi-gameserver.com/resource-service/test-
    lobby/index.html");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("main url");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Open Lobby with debug properties']")).click();
    System.out.println("lobby opened");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='brucelee']")).click();
    System.out.println("game loading");


    WebDriverWait  wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*
    [@id='spin-button']")));
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='spin-button']").click();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step:
Please add the following capability :

```
        cap.setCapability("automationName","MyTest");
```

Second step:

```
       Please replace the line :

         capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

         by this:
        cap.setCapability("browserName","Chrome");
```

Comment: I tried adding automatonName, but the appium is throwing below errors: 

[AndroidDriver] AndroidDriver version: 1.20.0
[BaseDriver] SessionNotCreatedError: A new session could not be created. Details: The desiredCapabilities object was not valid for the following reason(s):  automationName MyTest not part of Appium,Selendroid,UiAutomator2,XCUITest,YouiEngine,
    at AndroidDriver.validateDesiredCaps   at AndroidDriver.validateDesiredCaps (C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:155:25)